# does it need to realease AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

my code are as following:

```
    [session startRunning];

    avLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    avLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 , 416);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: avLayer];
    avLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

every time I start run session, I need to add AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to my view.

My question is: does it need to realease AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer before I add the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the memory for the objects,you need to release the memory for those objects.Here you didn't allocated memory.So no need to release it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to release the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.